# SpringBoot cannot provide jsp files in webapp Folder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new in springboot trying to simple webapp.

Using springboot  2.1.0 application.properties file like below.
I have jsp files in **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp**

```
  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
  spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

My controller is .

```
@Controller
class WelcomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun showWelcomePage(model: Model): String {
      model["name"] = "asdas"
      return "welcome"
    }
}
```

When I put jsp files in **/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp** it works  otherwise got below error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp
```

Also pom has tomcat-embed-jasper dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that jasper dependency and embedded tomcat dependency versions should be same otherwise it will be an issue.

Also try putting a jsp page outside itself like src/main/webapp/abc.jsp and remove view resolver and return directly like "abc.jsp" and see if that works.

see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLbvzF1-vXY) at 7:30

Comment: I tried but the same error occured . Using tomcat 9.0.12 and add tomcat-jasper 9.0.12  clear app properties , jsp files in directly under /webapp/   got same erroerThere was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/login.jsp

Comment: oh..:( curious to know why you want to use jsp instead of thymeleaf?

Comment: When I create a new project with intellij spring initializer and added jasper dependency it works thanks a lot .  Actually I have experience with jsp I start with it. Do you suggest thymeleaf instead of jsp?

Comment: yes ofcourse..great support from community and much advance than jsp.

Comment: try giving upvote and accept the answer if it helped you..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

are you using intellij? i had experience about same spring boot (jsp view) project is working in eclipse, but it's not work in intellij. i requested to jetbrain about this issue, they are say to me that "it's right, but we recomment use template engine like handlebars"